# How to add progress tracker for long running WCF service

Tags: c#, ajax, wcf

In my MVC app I am making a call to a WCF service which can take around 3 minutes.

The WCF basically takes a large input file and breaks it into smaller ones.

```
    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Index(Batch batch)
    {
        var batchSplitter = new BatchSplitterClient();
        var response =
            batchSplitter.SplitFile(new BatchSplitterRequest()
            {
                FilePath = "F:\\BatchFiles\\InputFile\\File_Tabbed_WithNull.txt",
                NumberOfRecordsPerFile = 1000
            });
        return View();
    }
```

The WCF basically just dumps the split files into an output directory.

How could I indicate some progress to client side, i.e. for each file created in output directory ?

```
// NOTE: You can use the "Rename" command on the "Refactor" menu to change the interface name "IService1" in both code and config file together.
[ServiceContract]
public interface IBatchSplitter
{
    [OperationContract]
    BatchSplitterResponse SplitFile(BatchSplitterRequest request);
}
```

Comment: The WCF service has to tell the client how far he got - either via his own API or via some WebAPI in your MVC project, so the client can poll the server on the progress.

Comment: I guess that's what I am wondering how to do it i.e. how do I relay back progress ? Do I need to add another service contract i.e. GetProgress ?